# Django support was removed from mongoengine

Tags: django, mongodb, python-2.7, python-3.x

[mongoengine-odm](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/changelog.html#changes-in-0-10-0) v0.10.0 says -

Django support was removed and will be available as a separate extension.

So, can anyone enlighten me on any present support of MongoDB and Django v1.8.x

Answer (score 1):

The documentation links to the extension.

https://github.com/MongoEngine/django-mongoengine

The story is the it became an extension,  but it seems to have active development.

Comment: I saw the docs, but i was asking for current version of mongoengine that's stable, if any.